# How to disable blue highlighting of text form field when selected in Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, forms

When a text form field is clicked in by the user, the field is highlighted in blue.

How can the blue highlighting be disabled?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot for before and after? I am not familiar

Comment: What do you mean by text form field ?

Comment: When posting a question about using something like Word, it will make it easier if you include the version. Per my response below, the instructions are different from Word 2003 to Word 2007 -- most things are as the interface changed a lot between versions.

Comment: If they are content controls, the Placeholder text is displayed against a pale blue background. Is that what you mean? I do not think that background can be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the field shading, similar to as detailed here, or as below for Word 2007: http://word.tips.net/T000554_Controlling_Field_Shading.html

> 1. Choose Options from the Tools menu. Word displays the Options dialog box.
> 2. Make sure the View tab is selected. (See image)

[image: View checkboxes for field shading]

> 3. Using the Field Shading drop-down list, specify how you want Word to handle field shading.
> 4. Click on OK.
>
> There are three options you can specify in step 3. The default is When
>   Selected, which simply means that the field is shaded when it is
>   selected or you place the insertion point within the field. If you set
>   the option to Never, then fields are never shaded, and (conversely)
>   Always specifies that they are always shaded.

For Word 2007:

1. Click the Word button (round button on top left)
2. Click the Word Options button
3. Under Show document content, in the Field shading list, do one of the following:

   - To make fields stand out from the rest of the document content, select Always.
   - To make fields blend in seamlessly with the document content, select Never.
   - To make users of Word aware that they have clicked in a field, select When selected.

[image: Field shading word 2007]

Note: When the field shading option is set to When selected, the field displays a gray background when you click within the field. However, the gray shading does not indicate that the field is selected. When you select the field by double-clicking or dragging the mouse, highlighting that indicates selection is added to the gray shading.

Comment: Even when this setting is set to `Never`, the field turns to blue when selected.

Comment: Are you using a modified interface like Classic menus?  Which version of Word? And do you mean when editing the form, or when filling it out?

Comment: Also, is there any chance that these are protected form fields?  Did you create the form, or are you just working with it?

Comment: @CJ7, A screenshot would really help clear things up :)

Answer (score -1):

In Word 2016 you can CTRL A to select all text, then click Styles under the home tab and then click remove formatting and that pesky pale highlight should disappear. Hope this works for you.